# Holomorphic function mapping rectangle into rectangle is linear polynomial

Tags: complex-analysis

According to Joseph Bak, Donald Newman Complex Analysis, If $f$ is holomorphic function  and $R \subset \mathbb{C}$ rectangle, s.t $f(R)=S \subset \mathbb{C}$ another rectangle, then $f$ can be extended to entire function, which is a linear polynomial.

*For the extension part, we can use Schwartz Reflection Principle to extend f into other 4
rectangles, builded on the boundary of $R$, and by such extensions we can get extension of $f$
all over the complex plane.

-I can't see how that reflection must be bounded by linear polynomial- which should be the way to conclude( using Liouville Thm), that f is such linear polynomial.

There are similiar questions, where the part of linear growth isn't clear to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is clearly false; possibly you didn't quote the book accurately (for example maybe the word "rectangle" is being used in a not quite standard sense, or maybe there are more conditions on $f$...).

Let $R=(0,1)\times(0,1)$ and $S=(0,1)\times(0,2)$. The Riemann mapping theorem shows that there exists a holomorphic $f$ with $f(R)=S$, but clearly if $p$ is a (complex-)linear polynomial then $p(R)\ne S$.

**Oh:** To make things easier to *state* let's assume in addition that $f$ extends continuously to the closure $\overline R$. Unless there's something you're not telling us, the reflection argument simply doesn't work unless we know somehow that if $E$ is any edge of $R$ then $f(E)$ is contained in a single edge of $S$.